# Vimeo API access token Expiry

Tags: oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am working on Vimeo API for a video streaming service and I have understood pretty much everything from the documentation.
My main concern is that I have not encountered any documentations on access token expiry.
So, can the access token expire once generated?  If yes then after how long? And can one refresh the token after expiry using the APIs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually is documented here:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

But in general I will say I've had nothing but trouble with the Vimeo API and absolutely detest their support and service. For a company pumping millions into advertising, their services kind of suck.

[NOTE: Expiration times for access tokens vary, depending on the type of the token and the way that the token is granted. Some access tokens have a limited lifespan. Others continue to work indefinitely, as long as you use them on a regular basis. To keep things running smoothly on our end, we automatically delete any tokens that appear to be inactive. For more information, see the descriptions of the individual authentication workflows below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr5VZ.png)

Answer (score 5):

I will just go ahead and answer my own question. After more reading I found out that the vimeo access token never expire. This is not documented though.

Comment: wrong....if the scope is is non public it expires in an our {
    "code": 124,
    "message": "Access token is expired."
}

Comment: My token I use in test server has never expired...its been a year so now. Maybe it is because I use it daily ?

Comment: how about vimeo returning refresh_token .... I am sorry but id didn't return no refresh_token

Comment: Vimeo APIs are really not that good. I gave up on them though I am still using their services.. LOL. For example our account has more than 3000 videos, users can move videos from one folder to another and there was need to tract this using the last modified field in the videos, It just not possible to get only videos modified in the last 1 hour or so. I had to fetch all the videos and check the last modified in my code.

Comment: Yeah I heard about vimeo api's being bad.... so i eventually emailed vimeo dev team for knowing the wheare about of refresh_token :'(  I really needed them

Comment: are you a video developer @Ayuka or a freelance dev

Comment: A freelance dev working on an e-learning platform. We have a studio to create content and we store the videos on vimeo. From there we use APIs to arrange the videos into topics. courses, lectures...

Comment: let me know If you want an extra helping hand @Ayuka .... I am looking for some side gigs :)