# Unable to get refresh_token from vimeo ouath

Tags: oauth-2.0, vimeo, vimeo-api, refresh-token

As per a standard ouath2.0 Authorization grant code glow. The code received in query can be used to get an access_token as well a refresh_token.

But I am not able to get refresh_token from vimeo. Just the access_token is being provided with the below curl

```
  curl 'https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token' \
      -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
      -H 'Referer: http://localhost:4200/vimeoCallback?code=0772xxxxsomeCode0003f7d818e207b' \
      -H 'Authorization: Basic YTMtxxxbasicbase64(KEY:ID)XXXXUg==' \
      -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --data-binary '{"grant_type":"authorization_code","code":"0772xxxxsomeCode0003f7d818e207b","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:4200/vimeoCallback"}' \
```

Please suggest me what I need to get the refresh_token

Answer (score 2):

Your message parameters look good - you just need to send them as form encoded data rather than as JSON - see [this link](https://reqbin.com/req/c-sma2qrvp/curl-command-to-post-a-form) for the syntax.

Comment: Thanks Gary . So you are suggestion instead of 'Content-Type: application/json' it should be formencoded....then i will get refresh_token as well....?

Comment: Could you please confirm that you have retrieved  refresh_token before in vimeo ?

Comment: Not in Vimeo - but the OAuth standard message is form url encoded, so highly likely that Vimeo uses that.

Comment: Yeah but if that had been the case...I would have not got access_token.... currently I am getting access_token , scope , expire etc ....but not refresh_token

Comment: Yep - looks like you're right and a [non standard format](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) is used, as opposed to the [standard format](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/refreshing-an-access-token/) security libraries will expect. I can't see any refresh token functionality at all, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535956/vimeo-api-access-token-expiry) suggests access tokens don't expire.

Comment: sorry ... I kept a authorization code generated access_token & its now {
    "code": 124,
    "message": "Access token is expired."
}

Comment: the never ending access_token is only for the public , unauthrozied scope & its pretty much useless...can't let you upload :'(